# Tokio future that reads from a channel and uses poll_fn and try_ready never completes

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

I have a Tokio future which never completes (`rx` is a `Receiver` and `sock` is a tokio `UdpSocket`). It basically reads packets from a packet queue and transmits them over a socket:

```
poll_fn(move || {
    match try_ready!(rx
        .poll()
        .map_err(|_e| tokio::io::Error::new(tokio::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Poll error")))
    {
        Some((packet, to)) => {
            println!(
                "Rx: Received {} bytes for {}: {:?}",
                packet.len(),
                to,
                packet.as_slice(),
            );
            try_ready!(sock.poll_send_to(packet.as_slice(), &to));
            println!("Sent");
        }
        None => println!("Rx end"),
    }
    Ok(futures::Async::Ready(()))
})
.map_err(|e: tokio::io::Error| println!("Error: {:?}", e))
```

It executes until the `poll_send_to` line (the `println!` just before `poll_send_to` executes, the `println!` just after doesn't) and then waits forever without sending the packet.

I replaced the above future with the following one to ensure that it wasn't a socket issue(had some issues with what I think were flaky notifications before):

```
poll_fn(move || {
    let packet = vec![0;10];
    let to = SocketAddr::from_str("127.0.0.1:8001").expect("Parse error");
    try_ready!(sock.poll_send_to(packet.as_slice(), &to));
    Ok(futures::Async::Ready(()))
})
.map_err(|e: tokio::io::Error| println!("Error: {:?}", e))
```

This future worked perfectly - it sent the packet as expected and exited the program.

I don't think the problem is with the message channels given that `rx` can `poll` successfully and prints the `println` message. I don't think the problem is with the socket either given that the second future works. I am observing packets directly through Wireshark, so I don't think it is an issue with my observations either.

I'm pretty new to Rust and Tokio, so it's possible that I am overlooking some basic fact (e.g. can't `try_ready` twice in the same future, future doesn't resume from where it left off previously, etc).

Can you help me figure out the problem with the first future?

```
use futures::future::lazy;
use futures::stream::Stream;
use futures::try_ready;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use std::str::FromStr;
use tokio;
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;
use tokio::prelude::future::poll_fn;
use tokio::prelude::Future;

fn main() {
    let mut sock = UdpSocket::bind(&SocketAddr::from_str("127.0.0.1:8000").expect("Parse error"))
        .expect("Bind error");

    let (mut tx, mut rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel::<(Vec<u8>, SocketAddr)>(2000);

    tokio::run(lazy(move || {
        //----------------- This future works ----------------//
        // tokio::spawn(
        //     poll_fn(move || {
        //         let packet = vec![70; 10];
        //         let to = SocketAddr::from_str("127.0.0.1:8001").expect("Parse error");
        //         try_ready!(sock.poll_send_to(packet.as_slice(), &to));
        //         Ok(futures::Async::Ready(()))
        //     })
        //     .map_err(|e: tokio::io::Error| println!("Error: {:?}", e)),
        // );

        //----------------- This future doesn't ----------------//
        tokio::spawn(
            poll_fn(move || {
                match try_ready!(rx
                    .poll()
                    .map_err(|_e| tokio::io::Error::new(tokio::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Poll error")))
                {
                    Some((packet, to)) => {
                        // This is printed
                        println!(
                            "Rx: Received {} bytes for {}: {:?}",
                            packet.len(),
                            to,
                            packet.as_slice(),
                        );
                        try_ready!(sock.poll_send_to(packet.as_slice(), &to));
                        // This is never printed
                        println!("Sent");
                    }
                    None => println!("Rx end"),
                }
                Ok(futures::Async::Ready(()))
            })
            .map_err(|e: tokio::io::Error| println!("Error: {:?}", e)),
        );

        //----------------- This future queues a packet ----------------//
        tokio::spawn(
            poll_fn(move || {
                try_ready!(tx.poll_ready());
                tx.try_send((
                    vec![70; 10],
                    SocketAddr::from_str("127.0.0.1:8001").expect("Parse error"),
                ))
                .expect("Send error");
                // Wait permanently so message channel doesn't get disconnected
                // Achieved differently in production
                Ok(futures::Async::NotReady)
            })
            .map_err(|e: tokio::sync::mpsc::error::SendError| println!("Error: {:?}", e)),
        );

        Ok(())
    }));
}
```

[Repo](https://github.com/roshanr95/tokio_mcve)

Comment: _"e.g. can't `try_ready` twice in the same future"_ — that macro just expands to a match expression, which returns on `Pending` or `Err` and otherwise unwraps the result, so there isn't a problem with calling it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this version of your future shows the problem:

```
tokio::spawn(
    future::poll_fn(move || {
        eprintln!("Starting poll_fn");

        let from_channel = rx
            .poll()
            .map_err(|_e| tokio::io::Error::new(tokio::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Poll error"));

        if let Some((packet, to)) = futures::try_ready!(dbg!(from_channel)) {
            futures::try_ready!(dbg!(sock.poll_send_to(packet.as_slice(), &to)));
        }
        Ok(futures::Async::Ready(()))
    })
    .map_err(|e: tokio::io::Error| println!("Error: {:?}", e)),
);
```

Here's the slightly cleaned-up output:

```
Starting poll_fn
[src/main.rs:21] from_channel = Ok(NotReady)

Starting poll_fn
[src/main.rs:21] from_channel = Ok(Ready(Some(/* ... */)))
[src/main.rs:22] sock.poll_send_to(packet.as_slice(), &to) = Ok(NotReady)

Starting poll_fn
[src/main.rs:21] from_channel = Ok(NotReady)
```

In words:

1. The future starts.
2. There's nothing ready from the channel; the channel registers a notification.
3. The future returns.
4. The channel gets a value and notifies the task.
5. The future starts again.
6. There's a value ready from the channel.
7. Sending on the socket is not ready; the socket registers a notification.
8. The future returns.
9. The socket is cleared and notifies the task.
10. The future starts again.
11. There's nothing ready **from the channel**; the channel registers a notification.
12. The future returns.
13. Nothing else is ever added to the channel.

In short, you aren't correctly maintaining your state machine inside of your future. You need to know how far you got the last time the future ran and start at that point the next time it ran.

There's a reason that the `async` / `await` syntax is much-anticipated: it will write these state machines for you.

I don't know *why* you've chosen to use the lower-level `poll`-based interface. I'd use the higher-level `Future`-based one:

```
tokio::spawn({
    rx.fold(sock, |sock, (packet, to)| {
        sock.send_dgram(packet, &to)
            .inspect(|_| println!("Sent it!"))
            .map(|(sock, _)| sock)
            .map_err(|e| panic!("Error: {:?}", e))
    })
    .map(drop)
    .map_err(|e| panic!("Error: {:?}", e))
});
```

---

> the `Future`-based interface [...] destroys the socket(and buffer) on error

This is a good reason to use the `poll`-based interface, but I'd still just dip into it long enough to implement your own future. Something like this:

```
struct X(UdpSocket);
struct XSendGram<D> {
    sock: Option<UdpSocket>,
    data: D,
    addr: SocketAddr,
}

impl X {
    fn send_dgram<D>(self, data: D, addr: SocketAddr) -> XSendGram<D> {
        XSendGram {
            sock: Some(self.0),
            data,
            addr,
        }
    }
}

impl<D> Future for XSendGram<D>
where
    D: AsRef<[u8]>,
{
    type Item = (X, usize);
    type Error = (X, std::io::Error);

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Result<Async<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        let mut sock = self.sock.take().expect("Future called after success or failure");

        match sock.poll_send_to(self.data.as_ref(), &self.addr) {
            Ok(Async::Ready(bytes)) => Ok(Async::Ready((X(sock), bytes))),
            Ok(Async::NotReady) => {
                self.sock = Some(sock); // Restore it for the next call
                Ok(Async::NotReady)
            }
            Err(e) => Err((X(sock), e)),
        }
    }
}
```

```
tokio::spawn({
    rx.fold(X(sock), |sock, (packet, to)| {
        sock.send_dgram(packet, to)
            .inspect(|(_, n)| println!("Sent {} bytes", n))
            .then(|r| match r {
                Ok((sock, _)) | Err((sock, _)) => future::ok(sock),
            })
    })
    .map(drop)
    .map_err(|e| panic!("Error: {:?}", e))
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It was indeed the state machine that was the issue. I was assuming async-await like semantics existing already(basically what I meant by "future doesn't resume from where it left off previously") instead of it executing the poll from the beginning every time. As for the `poll`-based interface, I just picked up the `echo-udp.rs` example from tokio(https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/examples/echo-udp.rs) to get started since it looked like a standard UDP server. Will begin switching to the `Future`-based one.

Comment: So, I looked at the `Future`-based interface and it destroys the socket(and buffer) on error. Is there no better option? E.g. an error that could possibly be handled using the `poll`-based interface without destroying the socket?